# How to formally prove that $A \subseteq \mathcal P(A)$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Since the the powerset is defined as $\mathcal {P}(A)=\{x\mid x\subseteq A\} $, it seems obvious that $A \subseteq \mathcal P(A)$. But I don't know how to show it formally.
Is it okay to say that $x\subseteq A$ (definition of a powerset), thus $A\subseteq \mathcal P(A)$?

It seems trivial, yet I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: In general $A\not\subseteq\mathcal{P}(A)$.

Comment: can you explain why please? or give an example? i'd like to understand my mistake

Comment: If $x \in A$ we have that $\{ x \} \subseteq A$, and thus $\{ x \} \in \mathcal P( A)$, for every $x \in A$. But from this does not follow that $x \in \mathcal P(A)$.

Comment: With $A= \{ 1,2 \}$ we have that $\mathcal P(A)$ has $4$ elements: $\mathcal P(A) = \{ \emptyset, \{ 1 \}, \{ 2 \}, A \}$. But $1 \notin \mathcal P(A)$.

Comment: Except in the context of axiomatic set theory, $A \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A)$ is never true for ontological reasons. For instance let $A = \mathbb{R}$. Then $A$ is a set of **numbers** while $\mathcal{P}(A)$ is a set of **sets of numbers**. Their elements are objects of **different types**, so elements of one can not belong to the other.

Answer (score 5):

Let $A=\{1\}$. Then $\mathcal P(A)$ has two elements: $\emptyset$ and $\{1\}$. But $A$ has one element: $1$. This element is not an element of $\mathcal P(A)$, so $A\not\subseteq\mathcal P(A)$. Note that $\{1\}$ and $1$ are not equal.

Answer (score 3):

$A \in \mathcal {P}(A)$ but in general $A \not\subseteq \mathcal {P}(A)$ because the *elements* of $A$ are not necessarily *subsets* of $A$.

Note the difference between $\in$ (is an element of) and $\subseteq$ (is a subset of).